# how to use href link and submit button in same tag with in a form

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, struts2

**My coding Part**

```
<form name="formid" name="myform"  action="add" method="post">
<c:forEach items="${subfilllist}" var="subFill">
<c:if test="${fillList.id == subFill.fillings}">                        
<span>      
<li class="list-group-item">                                             
<input type="checkbox" value="${subFill.fillingname}"  name="fillings"> ${subFill.fillingname}</input>
</li></span>
</c:if>
</c:forEach>
<a href="add?addcart${productDetailList.products_id}"onclick="myform.submit(); return false;">send</a>
</form>
```

*i want the href link and the form action should be in same action how can i do it..*

Comment: Shouldn't `name="myform"` rather be `id="myform"`? You seemed to have copy-paste the first `name` attribute :)

Comment: the link opreation perfom only the href link not passing the text box value

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: i want to pass the check box value and also the product id which i mention in href link to my action calss via this href link could you know how to do it

Comment: Why don't you just submit the form?